# Caesar encrypted ASCII text partially decrypted

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, ascii

I am trying to decrypt by brute force a Caesar encoded base 256 ASCII text.
The text in question is:

```
dy}uƒ0^u‡0b}q~K‹lvAlv‚}q~lv€‚Blvsxq‚ƒu„B0c‰}r|K‹lvBlvƒ‡yƒƒlv€‚Blvsxq‚ƒu„@0Q‚yq|K‹lvClv‚}q~lv€‚Blvsxq‚ƒu„@0\yru‚q„y~0cu‚yv‹l:lvq|„0dy}uƒ0^u‡0b}q~K‹lvDlvƒ‡yƒƒlv€‚Blvsxq‚ƒu„@0\yru‚q„y~0cq~ƒ‹l:lvq|„0Q‚yq|K‹lvElv‚}q~lv€‚@lvsxq‚ƒu„ABH0dy}uƒ0^u‡0b}q~K‹lvFlv~y|l
```

With this small java program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Run {
    private static FileWriter fr;
    static String b;
    private static BufferedReader br;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // encrypted file
        File enc_f = new File("caesar.rtf.enc");
        //decrypted file
        File dec_f = new File("caesar.rtf.dec");

        // init variables
        String text_enc = new String();
        String text_dec = new String();

        // read file
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(enc_f));
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; text_enc += line);
        char[] stringToCharArray = text_enc.toCharArray();

        // parse file and convert string to char
        for (int shift = 0; shift < 257; shift++) {

            for (char output : stringToCharArray) {

                // convert ascii to int
                int ascii = (int) output;

                // shift 
                ascii = ascii + shift;
                ascii = ascii % 256;

                // convert back to ascii
                char chTemp = (char) ascii;
                text_dec += chTemp;

            }

            // visual representation
            text_dec += System.lineSeparator();
            text_dec += System.lineSeparator();
            text_dec += shift;
            text_dec += System.lineSeparator();
            System.out.println(shift);

            // write decrypted file
            fr = new FileWriter(dec_f);
            fr.write(text_dec);

        }
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

After running the program I get at the shift number `239`a partial decrypted text (which is just part of the whole file to keep the executing time small) :

```
Timeí Neí Roman;íí\f1\fíoman\fííí2\fchaííeí2 Símbol;íí\f2\fííiíí\fííí2\fchaííeí0 Aíial;íí\f3\fíoman\fííí2\fchaííeí0 Libeíaíion Seíifí\*\falí Timeí Neí Romaní;íí\f4\fííiíí\fííí2\fchaííeí0 Libeíaíion Saníí\*\falí Aíialí;íí\f5\fíoman\fííí0\fchaííeí128 Timeí Neí Roman;íí\f6\fnil\
```

As it can be seen i can read Time new Roman but also the `í` where it's not supposed to be and i can't understand why, as if the shifts would not be correct than all the text should be wrong not just part of it. Also the encrypted text can be decrypted correctly.
If you have any idea, a hint would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: 239 doesn't seems as a correct shift because 'd' has ascii code 100 and if we add 239 or subtract it we will be outside of the 256 characters ascii table limit.

Comment: @AlexanderV. it shouldnt go outside the ascii limit, as i put 
'ascii = ascii % 256;' so it will revert back to the 256 limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a very basic mistake: confusing binary/bytes with character strings.

There is no such thing as "256 ASCII", ASCII is 7 bits, i.e. is encoded within  [0..127] and the first 32 and the last value is a *control character*.

What you are talking about is *bytes* and the operations should be performed on those. If you perform a calculation on a byte in Java it will automatically be within the range 0..255. You'd have to be careful though that the byte is not "promoted" to an integer, casting back using `(byte)` now and then.

So except the final print out your operations should all be on bytes. Using a `Reader` and `Writer` already may lose data as some characters may be left out. Just use the streams directly and then view the output in any text reader.

You can of course also use the fact that the output is between certain byte values (valid character encodings) to test if your solution is correct.

---

Note that we cannot test for you as your input "string" is likely already maimed. Encode it using base 64 or hexadecimals if you want to print it here.

Comment: Thank you! I dont know how i could made such a mistake. I did exactly what you told me, use 'Files.readAllBytes(path_to_file);' to read the bytes, converted them to unsigned one and then to integers.